# Wrong php email form

Tags: php, html, email

I've already spend hours on this simple code. Email arrives, but fields like name email newsletter are empty. It must be something stupid but it drives me crazzy that it's not working when it's just simple form. 
Also, if you know, can you please help me prevent user from clicking on form twice and sending multiple emails. Thank you a lot!

```
<?php
    $name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']));
    $email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['email']));
    $message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']));
    $newsletter = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['newsletter']));

    // Create the email and send the message
    $to = 'xxx@xxx.com'; 
    $email_subject = "Message from from :  $name";
    $email_body = "Message from form arrived.\n\n"."Message details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $newsletter\n\nMessage:\n$message";
    $headers = "From: form@xxx.com\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);          
?>



<form method="GET">
    <span>Name</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"><br />

    <span>E-mail</span>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br />

    <div>Message</div>
    <textarea type="text" name="message" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea><br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter">
    <label for="newsletter">I wold like to get email infromations</label><br />

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
    <span class="message"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: So, what does `$_GET` actually contain? What's does debugging reveal (printing the body, enabling error_reporting+notices)? Where did you take the pointless escaping from? What's your research/googling so far on the not-sending-twice part? (Two questions in one is not a thing here.)

Comment: The call to `htmlspechialchars()` does not make any sense. You do not place those strings inside html markup.

Comment: Best to prevent sending the form twice is to stop the habit to have both parts in a single file: form and form processing code. They belong in separate files. That way the form is removed in the browser view the moment it is submitted and you can display some confirmation or whatever instead.

Comment: `htmlspechialchars` typo there @arkascha ;-)

Comment: The question started being too broad after *"Also, if you know, can you please help me prevent user from clicking on form twice and sending multiple emails"*

Comment: and why 2 functions for a checkbox?

Comment: ` <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter">`   this needs a `value=1` or something

Comment: and we're all left *dangling* here; good luck with that.

Comment: sorry guys, was outside to clean my head. Yes, stackoverflow is my last rescue before giving up programing at all))) >> so I've deleted htmlspechialchars function, but this didn't helped. >> thank you for pointing out two separate files, will do them ... also of course thanks all for comments... will try to use constructive ones

Answer (score -3):

You may prefer HEREDOC syntax when working with lengthy strings that include variables, like you would use to generate email content. If your variables are being populated correctly, then this should work.

```
$email_body  = <<<EOT
 Message from form arrived.
 Message details:
 Name: $name
 Email: $email_address
 Phone: $newsletter
 Message:
 $message
EOT;
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question, does it?

Comment: Maybe.. I'm assuming his variables are being populated but aren't being parsed due to `$var\n\n`